# Create a tumbnail from a video binary

Tags: c#

How can i create a thumbnail from a video binary (bytes[])?

I do not have access to the directories, so i can't save the file and the example that I can see (using ffmpeg) to create a thumbnail is from a path.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: If you don't have file write permission . Other option is saving byte[] to db. Is this suitable for your situation?

Comment: yes, I have the file in the database. but the example that i found to create a thumbnail is always from a path

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, sampleBytes is our byte[] :

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(sampleBytes))
{
    Bitmap thumb = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    using (Image bmp = Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(thumb))
        { 
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
    }
    // this can show the result
    picBoxOut.Image = thumb;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get the thumbnail for the second 5, for example?

Comment: It seems for getting thumbnail of a video in a specific time, third party that able to give you all frames of video like ffmpeg is required.

Comment: but with ffmpeg can we get it from a byte[]?

Comment: ffmpeg does not support input as byte[] .

Comment: what’s is the alternative to get a Thumbnail for a specific second? Or is not possible?

Comment: This is possible with ffmpeg. Check this link https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.VideoConverter/?topic=html/M_NReco_VideoConverter_FFMpegConverter_GetVideoThumbnail_3.htm  . But need physical path to local video file as input Parameters.

Comment: so, without permission to the path is not possible right? I only have access to the bytes[]